# cannot match date day based on array data on database on php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have a leave date data in one month with various types of dates I try to match the data by date this month. when I make it based on row data only one date appears. I am a little less aware of the logic if it is an array.

My table

```
   | ID  |   id   |  start_date  |   end_date   | 
   | ____|________|______________|______________|
   |  1  |   x1   |  2018-11-05  |  2018-11-05  |
   |  1  |   x1   |  2018-11-12  |  2018-11-15  |
   |  3  |   x1   |  2018-11-19  |  2018-11-21  |
```

My script

```
    $timesheet = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->where('MONTH(start_date)', 11)
                      ->where('YEAR(start_date)', 2018)
                      ->where('id', 'x1')
                      ->get();
    $result = $timesheet->row_array();                    
    $day_start=date_create($result['start_date']);
    $day_end=date_create($result['end_date']);      

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 30; $x++) {
        if($x >=$day_start->format('d') and $x <= $day_end->format('d')){
           echo "<td class='bg-warning'>Y</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>N</td>";
        }
    }   

    /** MY result data **/

    | Date  | ... | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | ... | 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Result| ... | N |  N |  N |  Y | Y  | N  | N  |  N |  N | ... |


    /** the results I expected **/
    | Date  | ... | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | ... | 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Result| ... | N |  Y |  N |  Y | Y  | N  | Y  |  Y |  Y | ... |
```

Comment: You have `start_date` twice in your table, that might be a typo.

Comment: @SteeveDroz, thank you for being reminded, the meaning is the end_date field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge all of the records together, you will need to build up an array of the days (I create it using `array_fill()` and set each one to "N" to start).

You then iterate over each result row and add in the Y's to the appropriate elements.  You then loop over from the start to end day using a `for()` loop to fill in the days with a 'Y'.

Finally you can output the `$dates` array which has all of the various rows added into it.

```
$dates = array_fill(1, 30, "N");
foreach ($timesheet->result_array() as $result) {
    $start = (int)$result['start_date']->format('d');
    $end = (int)$result['end_date']->format('d');
    for ( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++ )   {
        $dates[$i] = "Y";
    }
}

foreach ( $dates as $day )  {
    if($day == "Y") {
        echo "<td class='bg-warning'>Y</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td>N</td>";
    }
}
```

You will probably want to change the `array_fill()` to have the correct number of days for the month you are working with, but this is something you can sort out as and when you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Nigel, not running, the date should be compared with the day
`if($x >=$day_start->format('d') and $x <=$day_end->format('d'))`

Comment: I've altered the way it picks out the days, can you check that as it may have been my testing.

Comment: Have you got any further with this?

Comment: With the current code (after the changes to `$start = (int)$r` and the next line), what do you get?

Comment: If you get nothing - try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start of the script which will display any errors.